# Fiware Keyrock - organizations are not returned

Tags: fiware, keystone, identity-management, identitymanager, fiware-wilma

I am needing the organizations info, from a specific user. This information is not returned as can be seen below:

```
organizations: [], displayName: 'idm', roles: [ { name: 'Provider', id: 'provider' } ],
```

I am getting an empty list of organizations. Even the owner of the organization receives an empty list.

Is this a bug? What can we do to get this information?

In my local instance I just get to do up to step 7 of this tutorial:

> http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/FIWARE_Lab:_Upgrade_to_Community_Account#How_can_authorize_other_users_to_use_my_cloud_resources.3F

I continue with this problem, waiting for some help...

Answer (score -1):

That response includes those organizations in which the user has roles assigned. So, it is not enough with belonging to an organization. If you have not roles assigned in that organization, it won't be included in the list.

To add roles to a user in an organization you have to follow the steps in http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/FIWARE_Lab:_Upgrade_to_Community_Account#How_can_authorize_other_users_to_use_my_cloud_resources.3F

Comment: Hello, @Álvaro . It is not possible to reproduce locally the steps from 7 onwards, following the link you put here. I can not access the `authorize` button as stated in the step 7. Could you explain me better, please, how to assign a role to a user in a specific organization? I thought the user roles were used to access application, without association with some organization. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any other suggestion, @Álvaro ?

Comment: What do you mean with "I cannot access the authorize button"? Please, check you have switched to the organization using the right-top corner panel. Then the button should appear.

Comment: I did all the steps in the link, but the problem continues: `organizations: []` and `'X-Organizations': '[]'`. Any other suggestion?