# Fiware Keyrock - organizations are not returned AGAIN

Tags: fiware, keystone

I'm encountering the same problem asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43591643/fiware-keyrock-organizations-are-not-returned).
 The list of organizations of an authenticated user `https://<idm_domain>/user?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxx` is **always** empty.
I tried to follow the [guide](http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/FIWARE_Lab:_Upgrade_to_Community_Account#How_can_authorize_other_users_to_use_my_cloud_resources.3F) reported in the previous post to solve my problem but as reported in the past question, I can't find the button **Authorize**, the point 7 in the guide, so it's impossible to achieve.
Someone can help me!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve the problem?

You can assign roles to users in organization directly from the dialog that appears when you press "manage" button. There you must assign some specific roles to the user, then you will see the organization in the list retrieved from the service.

[image]

[image]

If it does not work for you, just ask and we can continue working on it.

Comment: I'm sorry but I tried to add all roles to an organization for my user, but the list of organizations returned in the GET is always empty.